# Xamarin Studio doesn't want to use v14 C# 6 compiler

Tags: c#, monodevelop, xamarin-studio, c#-6.0

I'm currently trying to build a C# 6 project in Xamarin Studio (6.1.9) on a Windows 10 x64 computer.
I did some research and found some people saying that adding this to the .csproj file would fix the problem:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Unix'">
  <CscToolPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin</CscToolPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But no matter what I do, csc keeps telling me that '6' isn't a correct value for parameter /langversion, because Xamarin Studio always use the 4.0 csc no matter what I specified in the .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question, I thought about something. I went back in the .csproj file and noticed this at the beginning of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    ...
```

Notice the `ToolsVersion="4.0"`. I tried changing that into 14.0 and it worked instantly. The strange part is that my solution contained multiple projects that were using C# 6, and they were all giving errors. But changing the `ToolsVersion` for only the first project fixed all the errors (the other projects still have `4.0` instead of `14.0`, but XS builds them correctly.